# Thread1: Program Received Signal "SIGBRT"

Tags: objective-c, ios5, sqlite, xcode4.2

I'm working on sqlite database on ios 5. What my application does is that it takes strings in a textfield and saves it to the database. When I run the app, it crashes giving this warning:

> Thread1: Program Received Signal "SIGBRT"

It gives this in main.m and this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Can anyone help me with it? It'll be highly appreciated! :( I'm using xcode 4.2.

Here's the method where the compiler says that assertion failure has occurred.

```
- (void) addstrings{    
    if(addStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "insert into strings(strings) Values(?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [strings UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        strID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Comment: By "saves it to the database" do you mean you're calling SQLite directly, or using CoreData?  In either case, seeing the relevant code around the point of saving would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using sqlite 3 @wadesworld. I've checked the code many times yet no clue :(

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell exactly what's going on in your program without more information, but the most common reasons that abort() gets called are:

1. Your sending a message to an Objective-C object that doesn't support/implement that message. This results in the dreaded "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.
2. You have a failed assertion somewhere. In non-debug builds that define the macro NDEBUG, the standard library macro assert(3) calls abort() when the assertion fails.
3. You have some memory stomping/allocation error. When malloc/free detect a corrupted heap, that may call abort(). 
   That means that: You are freeing memory when it has already been done, probably by sending too many release messages to an object. Another thing is that you might have failed to connect an object to its IBOutlet in the nib. I can't really tell since you haven't given any other information aside from the reported error.
4. You're throwing an uncaught exception (either a C++ exception or an Objective-C exception).

In almost all cases, the debug console will give you a little more information about what's causing abort() to be called, so always take a look there.

Comment: the debug console tells there's an assertion failure. Can you tell me what might have been wrong in this case? Plus I'm using ARC enabled, so I'm not using any explicite release or delloc etc. Can you guide me?

Comment: Please take a look at the question again. I've edited it and made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

This `SIGABRT` error can occur in various condition,

Like you are trying to close `DB` without Opening the `DB`, or trying to write some value to `DB` without opening `DB`.

or may be several reason, so post some code here.

Comment: Ive edited the question and added the code of the method compiler finds buggy. Please guide me where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: `const char *sql = "insert into strings(strings) Values(?)";` what value will come in place of `(?)`

Comment: where you getting assertion failure ? while creating add statement or while inserting data ?

Comment: In place of (?), the value of strings in the textfield is to be saved.

Comment: Do `NSLog("sql query=%@",sql)` and copy this query and put it in sqlite and check whether it is working or not ?

Comment: in place of (?), the value of variable "strings" will be there. see the 7th line in the method above (sqlite3_bind_text)

Comment: you are giving value in 3rd line and binding value in 7th line, you will get null value in place of `(?)` and you will get `SIGABRT` place 3rd line as 1st line..

Comment: I know its dumb, but I didn't get it. Please explain :(

Comment: `const char *sql = ["insert into strings(strings) Values %@",sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [strings UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)];` write this line instead of your line and comment  `sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [strings UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);` this line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12210/discussion-between-ingila-ejaz-and-krunal)